# Starting a deploy on aws from a gitlab webhook and securing the process

Tags: amazon-web-services, gitlab

I want to trigger a deploy using aws when I push into a specific branch on my gitlab repository. I can do this with a webhook, and the setup is like this:

- I have created an endpoint via API Gateway that, when invoked, triggers a lambda function.
- The lambda function checks out the repository using credentials stored in S3 and deploys the result
- In gitlab I have created a webhook that calls the API Gateway Endpoint whenever I push to the specific branch

This setup is fine, there is only one concern I have:

I do not see how I could include credentials in the gitlab webhook. So the API gateway endpoint must be publicly accessible. So someone could call the URL and trigger an deploy when I do not want that.

Can I somehow secure this process?

Comment: What sort of application are you deploying?

Comment: It is a Website i compile with Hugo and deploy to s3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am in the process of building this kind of workflow as well, I have noticed you have a secret token in Gitlab, when a webhook is triggered GitLab sends "X-Gitlab-Token" in the headers, you could use that to then decide if the request is legit or not.